# Regain access to Apple ID traded away and 'returned'

Tags: apple-id

I was playing CoM (A game on the App Store that saves progress by Game Center), when this guy comes along and asks for an account trade. I agree because his account is awesome. So I trade, and he eventually gives me my Apple ID back and says that he takes the trade back. I try to log on but it said disabled for security reasons. I then panick because I put in a fake birthday for every thing that requires a birthday. I then make a new Apple ID with the same email and find that everything is gone including apps, progress and most importantly, iCloud.

Comment: What is an "account trade"?

Comment: Something that is most assuredly against the TOS of whatever game he is trying to play. @OP: Giving your Game Center login to another person is one of the worst things you could do, because as you have discovered, it is tied to all of your Apple accounts, as well as containing your app purchase history. There is nothing you can do to restore this information to a _new_ account. The best thing you can do is try to regain access to your old account. However, if you entered fake information for security questions/birthday, that seems to be unlikely to happen.

Comment: BTW, the term for what happened is you were 'socially engineered' or 'phished'. You willingly gave all your data to a scammer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know your security questions to reset your Apple ID, try the following.

- If you have 3 different security questions and a rescue email address set up with your Apple ID

Sign in to My Apple ID and select the "Password and Security" tab to send an email to your rescue email that you set up.

- If you have only 1 security question that you set up, but don't know your password

Contact apple support and hopefully someone can assist you farther.

Knowledge base related article: http://support.apple.com/HT201363